# SQL Query to get records from last week of every month for 4 years

Tags: sql, teradata

I have below table

```
ABC  Date 
200    2019-02-22
-200    2019-02-23
1200    2019-02-24
-500    2019-02-25
'
'
'
'
-889   2015-01-11
```

I need to get values for from ABC for every day of last week of every month

```
select ABC
from table 1
where date between '2019-03-26' and '2019-03-30'
```

this is for month of march 2019. How do i create a loop such that it displays value for everyday of last week of every month for 3 years

Comment: How do you define *last week* of a month? Full week, partial week? What is the start day of your week, Sunday or Monday?

Comment: Last week from 22-29, start day is Monday.....So basically I would check values from 22-29th of every month. Output would look something like this..    
ABC 200  date :2019-03-22, ABC 100 date :2019-03-22.........ABC 200 date :2018-02-22

Comment: *values from 22-29th of every month* = `where extract(day from mydate) between 22 and 29`

Comment: how will get it for all 3 years?...

Comment: `and mydate between add_months(current_date,-3*12) and current_date`, maybe `trunc(add_months(current_date,-3*12), 'mon')` to include the full 1st month.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ABC, DATE FROM table_1 WHERE DATEPART(wk, DATE) = 
DATEPART(wk, EOMONTH(DATE)) AND DATE <= DATEADD(year,3,GETDATE())
```

DATEPART(wk, DATE) gives me the week number of that date, DATEPART(wk,EOMONTH(DATE)) gives me the week number of (the last day of the corresponding date's month). So, when I check this, I will only select dates  belonging to the last week of every month. The next filter is to select only those dates which are lesser than 3 years from now (GETDATE()).

Comment: Microsoft successfully indoctrinates people sucessfully to believe that SQL is a synonym to SQL Server, but T-SQL is not the same as Standard SQL. None of your syntax is Standard SQL.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Will try to standardise it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date arithmetic to get the last week of each month.  In Terdata, I think this is one solution:

```
select abc
from table1
where (date >= (current_date - extract(day from date) * interval '1 day') - interval '6 day' and
       date <= current_date - extract(day from date) * interval '1 day'
      ) or
      (date >= (current_date - extract(day from date) * interval '1 day') - interval '1 month' - interval '6 day' and
       date <= current_date - extract(day from date) * interval '1 day' - interval '1 month'
      ) or
            (date >= (current_date - extract(day from date) * interval '1 day') - interval '2 month' - interval '6 day' and
       date <= current_date - extract(day from date) * interval '1 day' - interval '12month'
      );
```